# how to correlate cookies value of loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

web_add_cookie("JSESSIONID=s%3A1Yim88omE7km7CjHfJbIkYsG7s32F82m.d7U2czNHMD9PYItOK9pzPGyu4c0JeROSolDsQgSHpjY; DOMAIN=XXX");

web_add_cookie("**VCAP_ID**=5eebc8db-4f0d-42aa-77ac-31f9; DOMAIN=XXX");

The cookie should be change everytime and can't been correlation, how can i get this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8WZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Read your documentation.   Cookies are handled automatically in LoadRunner.   You only need to correlate values which appear in GET/POST/HEAD or other user based request going to the server

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are handled automatically within LoadRunner. You should parametrise anything that will be needed for requests further than the test.

You are getting an "Authentication Required" error.  You need to add a web set user to the top of your script.  This will allow you to get start a session with your script and add

```
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/ja/2020-2020_SP1/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_set_user.htm
```